# Can multiple ActiveMQ instances be used with Camel and Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

My project has the following setup :

A spring boot application, with an ActiveMQ and Apache Camel.
Camel is used to do all the configuration and instantiation.
This worked fine, but now another ActiveMQ, with another queue and url broker should be added (to be used only as consumer).

During the configuration process, `org.apache.camel.jms.JmsComponent` is getting the JMSConfiguration by retrieving all classes of type ConnectionFactory.
More specific: by calling `applicationContext.getBeansOfType(ConnectionFactory.class);`

This returns a `Map<String, ConnectionFactory>`, containing the ConnectionFactories and their names (=keys).  However always the first ConnectionFactory is returned.
And because in the project 2 ConnectionFactories are defined, this leads to an error.

Is there a way to indicate which ConnectionFactory should be used together in Camel ?
The following code is from org.apache.camel-jms.JmsComponent, and the line

`ConnectionFactory cf = beansOfTypeConnectionFactory.values().iterator().next();`

is causing the issue, as it always takes the first ConnectionFactory.

```java
public JmsConfiguration getConfiguration() {
    if (configuration == null) {
        configuration = createConfiguration();

        // If we are being configured with spring...
        if (applicationContext != null) {

            if (isAllowAutoWiredConnectionFactory()) {
                Map<String, ConnectionFactory> beansOfTypeConnectionFactory = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(ConnectionFactory.class);
                if (!beansOfTypeConnectionFactory.isEmpty()) {
                    ConnectionFactory cf = beansOfTypeConnectionFactory.values().iterator().next();
                    configuration.setConnectionFactory(cf);
                }
            }

            if (isAllowAutoWiredDestinationResolver()) {
                Map<String, DestinationResolver> beansOfTypeDestinationResolver = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(DestinationResolver.class);
                if (!beansOfTypeDestinationResolver.isEmpty()) {
                    DestinationResolver destinationResolver = beansOfTypeDestinationResolver.values().iterator().next();
                    configuration.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return configuration;
}
```

The configuration in my project to setup with Camel :

```java
@Configuration
public class CamelContextConfiguration extends CamelConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected void setupCamelContext(CamelContext camelContext) throws Exception {
        super.setupCamelContext(camelContext);

        MyProjectDataFormat myprojectDataFormat = new MyProjectDataFormat();
        DataFormatDefinition projectDfd = new DataFormatDefinition(myprojectDataFormat);
        camelContext.getDataFormats().put("myproject", projectDfd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create two instances of the Camel JMS component, like:

```
@Bean 
JmsComponent jms1() {
    JmsComponent component = new JmsComponent();
    component.setConnectionFactory(...));
    
    return component;
}
@Bean 
JmsComponent jms2() {
    JmsComponent component = new JmsComponent();
    component.setConnectionFactory(...));
    
    return component;
}
```

And then reference the new components in your route, as example:

```
from("jms1:...")
    .to("jms2:...")
```

The other option is to use the *connectionFactory* option:

```
from("jms1:...?connectionFactory=#cf1")
    .to("jms2:...?connectionFactory=#cf2")
```